# Install mediation ironsource repo android admob

Tags: android, admob, mobile-ad-mediation, ironsource

Reading the [doc](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/mediation/ironsource), to implement ironSource as a mediation waterfall on AdMob we have to add `com.google.ads.mediation:ironsource:7.2.7.0` but this repo have a dependency to `com.ironsource.sdk:mediationsdk:7.2.7` which does not exist https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.ads.mediation/ironsource/7.2.7.0

I maybe have the wrong approach to install it